Why isn't there an e-paper tech with different colors in different subpixels?
As of right now in late 2024 E-Ink has two technologies for color e-paper:
E-Ink Kaleido puts a grid of color filters on top of a black-and-white e-paper display like a color reflective LCD.
E-Ink Gallery puts CMYW electrophoretic particles in every cell and then plays a complicated multi-step dance of voltages to select between them over the course of a second or so.
Why don't they have a technology that only has CW/MW/YW/KW in each cell in an ordered Bayer or subpixel pattern?  That seems like the obvious approach that would give better results so I assume there's a reason they don't.
Is the electrophoretic material actually made unordered so they can't do any patterning except in the address layer?  Or is there some other physical limitation?

Wenting Zhang did a kind of overview of this in his talk  on speeding up e-ink at Supercon a couple weeks ago.
Even B&W gray scale is not all that great, and when you get color you lose elsewhere:


That's what I'm talking about. Both of the technologies seem too compromised to release outside the spot color used in their price labels. You don't seem to have provided an answer though.
